# How to light up specific LED's and also shift every other led with a 74HC595 shift register?

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega, shift-register

I am currently in the process of building a drum machine with a micro controller. I am trying to figure out the logic of the sequencer. I have 16 LED's which will indicate at which 16th note the drum machine currently is playing.

So for instance, let's say the beats per minute (BPM) is 120, then the led should shift twice every second.

So for the shifting part I have written code such that if the step number is 0, we shift in a 1. If the step number is > 0, we shift in a 0. The method is called every (60/BPM) seconds.

PD5 is the serial input,
PD4 is the latch pin, PD3 is the clock pin.

```
void update_led(void) {
    if (step_number == 0){
       PORTD |= (1 << PD5); //Send a 1
       PORTD |= (1 << PD4); //Read the input to 1st led
       PORTD &= ~(1 << PD5);
       PORTD &= ~(1 << PD4);
       PORTD |= (1 << PD3); //Shift to next led
       _delay_ms(40);  //Apparently I need a delay here to light up LED
      PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3);
    }else{
      PORTD |= (1 << PD4);
      PORTD &= ~(1 << PD4);
      PORTD |= (1 << PD3);
      _delay_ms(40);
      PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3);
   }
 }
```

But I also want the LEDs to static be lit for each step a user has programmed a sound. So for instance if the user presses button 1 and 5 and 9 and 13 with the instrument kick drum, the LED 1,5,9,13 should be static lit up but the leds should also shift like the above code. Does anyone have any tips on how to efficiently implement this? Is there a smart way to make a specific LED always light up when shifting the other LED's?

Comment: I would just keep the desired state of all LEDs in a variable. Every time it changes, shift the necessary bits through _all_ the LEDs to update them to the latest state.

Comment: How do I correctly declare such a variable? Let's say that I have step_number currently at step 8, and selected steps are at 1, 5, 9, 12. I want to have one array "current_step" with a 1 set at the 8th index. One array "selected_steps" with a 1 set at index 1,5,9,12. I then want to have a "final_led" array which is final_led = XOR(current_step, selected_steps). I am not very experienced with C so I have trouble defining these arrays correctly.

Comment: You're on the right track! But "how to declare arrays" is material for a different question. One that's probably been answered many times, so just search around a bit :)

Comment: Yes I get that, thank you for taking the time to answer me! My second question shouldn't be hard to find out haha.